# How many different strings of length $100$ may be composed of $10$ different $10$ position binary numbers?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, bit-strings

"**How many different strings of length $100$ may be composed of $10$ different $10$ position binary numbers?**"

So this series would be divided into $10$ segments of $10$ bits. Maximum number of options at one segment is $2^{10}$, my idea is that I choose $2^{10}$ for each of those segments and therefore do $10!$ to permute them, although in this case those strings wouldn't differ from each other, any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: $10!$ is correct. If the strings are distinct, the compositions are distinct as well.

Comment: That's right, but how do I choose those bits on those 10 segments

Comment: I assumed that the $10$ distinct strings are already given.

Comment: No I need to choose those 10 strings of 10 bits, as I anwsered under below anwser : " So ($2^{10} * (2^{10} -1 ) * (2^{10} -2 ) * (2^{10} -3 ) * (2^{10} -4 ) *(2^{10} -5 ) *(2^{10} -6) *(2^{10} -7 ) *(2^{10} -8 ) *(2^{10} -9 )* 10!$  Is that right?

Answer (score 3):

There are $2^{10}$ ways to fill the first $10$ digits.  Since the next ten digits must differ from the first ten digits, they can be selected in $2^{10} - 1$ ways.  Can you continue?

Comment: So ($2^{10} * (2^{10} -1 ) * (2^{10} -2 ) * (2^{10} -3 ) * (2^{10} -4 ) *(2^{10} -5 ) *(2^{10} -6) *(2^{10} -7 ) *(2^{10} -8 ) *(2^{10} -9 )* 10!$  Is that right?

Comment: Not quite.  You have already accounted for the order by choosing which string is first, which is second, and so forth, so there is no need to multiply by $10!$.  To see this, consider the related problem of finding the number of permutations of three different digits selected from the ten decimal digits.  We can select the first digit in $10$ ways.  For each such choice, we can select the second digit in $9$ ways.  For each such choice, we can select the third digit in eight ways.  Therefore, there are $10 \cdot 9 \cdot 8$ such strings.

Comment: So my anwser is good but without $10!$ right? I get it now

Comment: Yes, that is correct.